# Java- Why Selenium Chrome webdiver is using my real IP adress instead of the proxy

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to browse with Selenium using a proxy but it fails and show my public IP instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driverChrome.exe");
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("200.111.182.6:443");
    option.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: @DebanjanB  thanks but your code didn't solve my problem i posted an answer that worked just by using arguments thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the *Java Docs* [`setCapability()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#setCapability-java.lang.String-boolean-) method from [MutableCapabilities](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) is defined as:

```
setCapability
public void setCapability(java.lang.String key, java.lang.Object value)
```

So instead of `setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy)` you have to use `setCapability("proxy", proxy);`. So effectively your code block will be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driverChrome.exe");
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("200.111.182.6:443");
    option.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

---

### tl; dr

[Capabilities & ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driverChrome.exe");
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://51.38.22.57:8522");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```